# Laravel date search funtion

Tags: php, laravel

how to add date search like DATE_FROM and DATE_TO? i have already existing  controller using search box and drop-down filter to my blade template, now how do i add date range filter. and also how to add it inside my date-picker in blade

**Note:** *in my database i only have the default created_at column*

Controller:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{

    $search=$request->input('search'); 

    if(request()->has('lead_status')){
        $leads=Lead::where('lead_status', request('lead_status'))
        ->paginate(5)
        ->appends('lead_status',request('lead_status'));
    }
    else{

        $leads=Lead::orderBy('created_at','desc')->search($search)->paginate(5);

    }

    return  view ('leads.index')->with('leads',$leads);

}
```

**VIEW Date-Picker**

```html
 <div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
    <label>FROM</label>
    <input type="date"  name="" value="" class="form-control">
                               
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 form-group">
    <label>TO</label>
    <input type="date"  name="" value="" class="form-control">
                               
</div>
```

Comment: Simple use `BETWEEN` like this `->whereBetween('created_at',[$from_date,$to_date]);`

Comment: You have search box and lead status box also?

Comment: yes sir i have it

Comment: thats why im abit confuse where to add the date search with in those code

Answer (score 0):

With where date you can search by the date 
and may more at here [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#where-clauses)

```
Lead::whereDate('created_at', '=', date('Y-m-d'))->get();
```

WhereBetween

```
Lead::whereBetween('created_at', [date('Y-m-d', strtotime($input['from'])), date('Y-m-d', strtotime($input['to']))])->get();
```

Your soluation

```
$leads = Lead::query();
    if($request()->has('lead_status')){
        $leads = $leads->where('lead_status', $request('lead_status'));
    }
    if($request()->has('from') && $request()->has('to')){
    {
        $from_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request()->has('from')));
        $to_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request()->has('to')));
        $leads = $leads->whereBetween('created_at', [$from_date, $to_date]);
    }

    $leads = $leads->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(5);
```

Comment: how do i put this into my blade view?

Comment: check the updated answer you need to add the condition for your search filters

Comment: how bout my blade template how do i arranged it?

Comment: add name in the input box, name="from",name="to"

Answer (score 0):

And in your controller access the request input parameter like so:
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

```html
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $search= $request->input('date');
    $leads=Lead::where('lead_status''=', $search)->get();

    return  view ('leads.index')->with('leads',$leads);
}
```

**ROUTE with** 
`Route::get('/leads/{date}', 'YourControllerName@index');`